# AWS DMS - Task failed when migrating Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, aws-dms

I'm trying migrate a Oracle database to AWS RDS using AWS DMS, however the task is failing:

```
2018-05-18T13:57:30 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task 'NEAH4DHCL65GY5WNXKFJCQ6QJQ' running full load and CDC in fresh start mode (replicationtask.c:1078)
2018-05-18T13:57:30 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task Id: 80e1f63b-e4e3-4ee7-bc61-2ce40f2c2119 (replicationtask.c:2700)
2018-05-18T13:57:31 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Creating threads for all components (replicationtask.c:1681)
2018-05-18T13:58:06 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Threads for all components were created (replicationtask.c:1836)
2018-05-18T13:58:06 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task initialization completed successfully (replicationtask.c:2759)
2018-05-18T13:58:06 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Target endpoint 'Oracle' is using provider syntax 'Oracle' (provider_syntax_manager.c:589)
2018-05-18T13:58:06 [TARGET_APPLY ]I: Working in transactional apply mode (endpointshell.c:1440)
2018-05-18T13:58:07 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Source endpoint 'Oracle' is using provider syntax 'Oracle' (provider_syntax_manager.c:583)
2018-05-18T13:58:07 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Use any Oracle Archived Log Destination (oracle_endpoint_imp.c:723)
2018-05-18T13:58:07 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Oracle CDC uses LogMiner access mode (oracle_endpoint_imp.c:732)
2018-05-18T13:58:07 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: retry timeout is '120' minutes (oracle_endpoint_imp.c:879)
2018-05-18T13:58:07 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Scale is set to 10 for NUMBER Datatype (oracle_endpoint_imp.c:906)
2018-05-18T13:58:07 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Retry interval is set to 5 (oracle_endpoint_imp.c:914)
2018-05-18T13:58:07 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Oracle database version is 11.2.0.4.0 (oracle_endpoint_conn.c:645)
2018-05-18T13:58:09 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]I: Oracle compatibility version is 11.2.0.4.0 (oracle_endpoint_conn.c:91)
2018-05-18T13:58:09 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: CDC cannot be provided because supplemental_log_data_min in v$database is set to NO [1020401] (oracle_endpoint_conn.c:131)
2018-05-18T13:58:09 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Minimal database supplemental logging level is not enabled [1020418] (oracle_endpoint_imp.c:1009)
2018-05-18T13:58:09 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Failed while preparing stream component 'st_0_MQO5EJYIINY5SSEAQEG64Y7TQY'. [1020418] (subtask.c:853)
2018-05-18T13:58:09 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Cannot initialize subtask [1020418] (subtask.c:1258)
2018-05-18T13:58:09 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Stream component 'st_0_MQO5EJYIINY5SSEAQEG64Y7TQY' terminated [1020418] (subtask.c:1513)
2018-05-18T13:58:10 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Subtask #0 ended (replicationtask_util.c:937)
2018-05-18T13:58:10 [TASK_MANAGER ]E: Task error notification received from subtask 0, thread 0 [1020418] (replicationtask.c:2379)
2018-05-18T13:58:10 [TASK_MANAGER ]W: Task 'NEAH4DHCL65GY5WNXKFJCQ6QJQ' encountered a fatal error (repository.c:4760)
2018-05-18T13:58:11 [TASK_MANAGER ]I: Task management thread terminated (replicationtask.c:3235)
```

I can't see anything usefull in the above log. What could be causing this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
2018-05-18T13:58:09 [SOURCE_CAPTURE ]E: Minimal database supplemental logging level is not enabled [1020418] (oracle_endpoint_imp.c:1009)
```

You have not set the level Minimal Supplemental Logging for database level.
You need run sql as sysdba for set Minimal Supplemental Logging.

```
[oracle@db-03 ~]$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Wed May 23 07:51:16 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> ALTER DATABASE ADD SUPPLEMENTAL LOG DATA;

Database altered.

SQL> SELECT supplemental_log_data_min FROM v$database;

SUPPLEME
--------
YES

SQL>
```